# Tablesorter Scroller widget bootstrap not allowing click events to bubble in frozen columns

Tags: tablesorter

I'm attempting to use TableSorter with the latest Scroller widget, but I am having problems getting the click event to bubble in a frozen column. I can get the hover psuedo class to fire on the icons, but for the life of me, I cannot get the click handler to fire. Any ideas?

```
    <table id="groupAttrTable" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-sorter="false">Action</th>
                <th>Key 1</th>
                <th>Key 2</th>
                <th>Key 3</th>
                <th>Value 1</th>
                <th>Value 2</th>
                <th>Value 3</th>
                <th>Value 4</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Last Updated By</th>
                <th>Last Updated Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-attrID="1">
                <td>
                    <div class="regMode">
                        <a class="editAttr">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                        </a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a class="hideAttr">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="unhideAttr">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editMode" style="display: none;">
                        <a class="confirmAttr">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                        </a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a class="cancelAttr">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>Some Text</td>
                <td>Some Text</td>
                <td>Some Text</td>
                <td>Some Text</td>
                <td>Some Text</td>
                <td>Some Text</td>
                <td>Some Text</td>
                <td>Some Text</td>
                <td>Some Text</td>
                <td>Some Date</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>    

$("#groupAttrTable").tablesorter({
            theme : "bootstrap",
            headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}',
            widgets : [ "uitheme", "filter", "zebra", "scroller"],
            widgetOptions : {
              zebra : ["even", "odd"],
              scroller_fixedColumns: 4,
              scroller_height: 400,
              filter_external: ".groupAttrFilter",
              filter_defaultFilter: {'all':"~{query}"},
              filter_reset: ".groupAttrReset",
              filter_columnFilters: false
            }
        });

$(".hideAttr").on("click", function(e){
        console.log("hide attribute");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The scroller widget needs to make multiple copies of the tbody. And every time the browser window gets resized, or the table is sorted or filtered, the fixed column gets rebuilt.

So, to make the click work, you'll need to use [delegated event bindings](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). Target the `body` of the page, or any wrapper of the table, not the table itself:

```
$('body').on('click', '.hideAttr', function(e){
    console.log('hide attribute');
}
```